# how can we read the exact potentiometer value?

Tags: potentiometer

Can you please How can we check if we have the correct value from a potentiometer in a circuit?

thanks for your help

Comment: Well, what circuit would this be? Can you expand on the details.

Comment: The question is unclear, what do you mean correct value? Which value?

Comment: That rather depends on the circuit that the potentiometer is in.  Measuring a potentiometer by itself is easy.  Measuring one that is surrounded by other components may be extremely difficult.

Comment: Welcome to the site. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You use a Wheatstone Bridge.

[Wheatstone Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge)

A Wheatstone Bridge is a simple circuit that allows you to determine the resistance of a resistor with an unknown value. The circuit uses a voltage source, two resistors with known values, an adjustable resistor (potentiometer or resistor you swap out by hand), and a volt meter. You adjust the value of the adjustable resistor until the voltmeter reads zero. At that point, you use Kirchoffs laws to calculate the value of the unknown resistor.

Or, use a constant current source, run it through the potentiometer, read the voltage across the potentiometer, and calculate the resistance with V = IR .

There are lots of other ways to do this as well I'm sure.